# how to add button inside a editable table tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have a table which is editable  i use mindmup-editabletable.js.for editable table.but now i want a button inside the tr i try some code

```js
$(function() {
  $('#tabledata').editableTableWidget();
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#tabledata tr > td:first-child").html("<button class=collapsebutton>-</button> " + OriginalContent + " ");
  });
});
```

```css
.tabletd {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgb(158, 190, 215);
  height: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/mindmup-editabletable.js"></script>
<table id="tabledata">
  <tr>
    <td>
      new
    </td>
    <td>
      hi
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>add -</button>
```

but now the button i insert the code is also editable one i don't want it .i want the button is fixed one not a editable one

Comment: Your snippet is broken. You need to add a reference to `mindmup-editabletable.js` from a CDN

Comment: now i can edit it .but how i fix the button as not editable one